# Sincronizar MySQL e SQL SERVER através de script PHP

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sincronização

Preciso sincronizar o SQL Server (Master) com o MySQL (Slave).

Já encontrei algumas maneiras de como fazer isso na internet, como por exemplo o recurso nativo do SQL Server "Linked Server" ou aquele APP para windows DBSync. Mas queria saber se tem a possibilidade de fazer isso com algum script em PHP ou outra linguagem de programação.

Já procurei no google, porém não encontrei scripts, apenas isso que citei acima. Não consigo pensar em algum algoritmo que localize apenas as linhas editadas no SQL SERVER e atualize as linhas no Mysql.

Comment: Acho que algo que resolvesse seu problema seria algo mais complexo do que o próprio SQL Server e o MySQL juntos. Por que você não utiliza apenas um dos dois? Assim seria um simples caso de backup/replicação incremental.

Comment: Avalie a criação de um job no SQL Server, usando a conexão via linked server. Basta definir a frequência com que a replicação será atualizada. // Há alguma regra que define o que foi modificado, desde a última atualização do sincronismo? // Envolve uma ou várias tabelas?

Comment: Então, a utilização apenas de um banco é inviável visto que tenho dois sistemas integrados, cada um com seu banco (Mysql e SQL SERVER), para fazer conexão linked-server seria uma última solução, pois não tenho um master user do SQL SERVER e gostaria de poder resolver este problema com algum script mesmo, até com php se fosse possível, pois assim apenas colocaria na rotina CRONTAB do linux, porém minha dificuldade é fazer a atualização das tuplas, não consigo pensar em uma lógica funcional.